# how to give pods in namespace an admin access?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm new to k8s.

I have a deployment with a single pod inside `k8test` (custom) namespace. ***for learning purposes***, I want to give that pod an admin access.

I failed to achieve this by creating a namespace-role:

```
    kind: 'Role',
    apiVersion: 'rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1',
    metadata: {
      name: 'super-duper-admin',
      namespace: 'k8test',
    },
    rules: [
      {
        apiGroups: [''],
        resources: ['ResourceAll'],
        verbs: ['VerbAll'],
      },
    ],
```

from the pod`s log:

> services is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:k8test:default" cannot list resource "services" in API group "" in the namespace "k8test"

- I couldn't find a simple explanantion to what is `apiGroups`. What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find all api groups [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#-strong-api-overview-strong-).

As documented [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-overview/#api-groups)

> API groups make it easier to extend the Kubernetes API. The API group
>   is specified in a REST path and in the apiVersion field of a
>   serialized object

Pod comes under `core` API Group and version `v1`.

In your RBAC `''` indicates the `core` API group.

Create the role as below which gives permission to all `apigroups`, all `resources` and all `verbs`.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: k8test
  name: super-duper-admin
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - '*'
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - '*'
```

Bind the role to the service account as below

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
# This role binding allows "jane" to read pods in the "default" namespace.
# You need to already have a Role named "pod-reader" in that namespace.
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: admin-rolebinding
  namespace: k8test
subjects:
# You can specify more than one "subject"
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default # "name" is case sensitive
  namespace: k8test
roleRef:
  # "roleRef" specifies the binding to a Role / ClusterRole
  kind: Role #this must be Role or ClusterRole
  name: super-duper-admin # this must match the name of the Role or ClusterRole you wish to bind to
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Execute below command to verify the RABC is properly applied

```
kubectl auth can-i list services --as=system:serviceaccount:k8test:default -n k8test
```

More information and examples about RBAC [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)

Comment: 1. what is the difference between my role and your role? what was my mistake?

Comment: 2. thanks for quoting the docs for api-groups but I'm still not understanding what problem does it try to solve and how does it solve it?

Comment: ' ' means core API Group and * means all API Group. Apart from creating a role you need to create a rolebinding as well. Can you tell me more about what you mean by admin? What permission you want to give it?

Comment: I have an error when I try to create the role: `Role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "super-duper-admin-role" is invalid: rules[1].nonResourceURLs: Invalid value: []string{"*"}: namespaced rules cannot apply to non-resource URLs`

Comment: Remove the non resource section..updated the answer. it's applicable for clusterole not for role

Comment: the verifu command returns: "no". can we keep this conversation in the chat?

Comment: I had a typo in the yaml, its working great! thank you for all your help!!